# How update pptx file particular slide element with same style in php laravel

Tags: powerpoint

I have try with PHPpresentation and other expentions please let us know if you have anything.

Tried below code but not working -

```
public function getSlide($slideNumber)
    {
        // Path to the PPT file
        $pptPath = storage_path('app/public/slides/sample.pptx');

        // Load the PPT file using PHPPresentation
        $presentation = IOFactory::load($pptPath);

        // Get the slide by slide number
        $slide = $presentation->getSlide($slideNumber);

        // Convert the slide to HTML
        $html = $slide->toHtml();

        return view('slides.show', compact('html'));
}
```